# How to clear EE native cache and CE Cache

Tags: cache, ce-cache, caching

I have got a site that has both EE caching applied and CE Cache module. I have updated the html mark-up in the template but my changes aren't showing through.

There are several cache parameters for EE tags which I have set to one minute. I have reloaded the pages couple minutes later and still have the old version.

Also, I have set CE cache module tag that's wrapped around the template ({exp:ce_cache:it id="page" seconds="1"}) to one second and have cleared the "Clear Driver Site Cache" in the admin/control panel.

Anything else am suppose to be doing?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can clear EE cache from Control Panel -> Tools -> Data -> Clear Caching.

For CE Cache:

Go to CE Cache module settings. Click "View Items" next to either File or Database driver (the method of cache store, usually File).
Here you can clear the cache by clicking "Delete Children".